# How to cancel HttpClient GET Web request

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, c#-5.0

Is it possible to cancel `HttpClient GET web request in Windows 8.` I am looking for a solution to cancel my web request if the user press back key from the page. In my app i am using a `static class` for creating web request.

Alos i am using `MVVM Light`, and `static viewmodels` inside the app.

In the current situation, even if the user press the back button, 
the `vm` stay alive and the call back reaches and executes in the `VM`.

So i am looking for a solution to cancel the request on back press.

Comment: You can use CancellationToken for cancelling async methods. It's a way of doing it, might be others.

Comment: Can you please add the way of cancel the request with CancelationToken, as answer. Then i will mark it as answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    await HttpGetRequest();
}

public CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
private async Task HttpGetRequest()
{
    try
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppaidapplications/limit=400/genre=6000/json");
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(message, cts.Token);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("HTTP Get request completed. Time taken : " + (DateTime.Now - now).TotalSeconds + " seconds.");
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("HTTP Get request canceled.");
    }
}

private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cts.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: Please note, that for Windows 8.1 runtime things have changed "just a little" bit - [http client cancel request in windows 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457797/http-client-cancel-request-in-windows-8-1), so the currect answer is accurate only for runtime in windows 8.0.

Comment: OP has also asked for W8 only. See the tags of question.

Comment: I've seen tags for sure and your answer is perfectly fine for Windows 8. Just added comment for those, who like me may look the similar info for latest (so far) Windows and point them to the appropriate place.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Farhan Ghumra is correct. Since we have moved to .Net 6 just like to add the following to the answer.

After you’re completely done with the CancellationTokenSource, dispose it directly E.g use `cts.Dispose()` (because you’ll most likely be using this with UI code and needing to share it with click event handling code, which means you wouldn’t be able to dispose of it with a using block)

More information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.dispose?view=net-6.0).