# http client cancel request in windows 8.1

Tags: c#, networking, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a Windows Phone 8.1 project. There are two versions of http client in Windows 8.1  - `system.net.http` and `windows.web.http`. Microsoft recommends using the later.

So, I decided to go with it. But I can't find a way to cancel the web request started with `windows.web.http.httpclient`. In `system.net.http.httpclient` there is a [`CancelPendingRequests`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.cancelpendingrequests%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method but no similar methods exist for the later option.

So, is it possible to cancel the web request and if so how?

Sample Code:

Consider a `Http Get` request google as follows.
I would like to cancel it before its completion if the user wishes so.

```
// Windows Phone 8.1 project (not silverlight)
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

        Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += (s, e) =>
        {
           CancelGet();
        }
    }

    private void CancelGet()
    {
       // What to put here??
       // tried client.Dispose();
       // but still get request completes successfully
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string res = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute));

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("result obtained\n" + res);
    }
 }
```

None of the methods of HttpClient support CancellationToken.

Also I tried to call Dispose() on the HttpClient  while the request is ongoing (say GetStringAsync). However still neither any exception is thrown nor the request is cancelled; the GetStringAsync completes as normal and shows the correct result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Haven't tested it yet, but this could work:

```
await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com")).AsTask(cancellationToken);
```

If you don't have the need for cancellation tokens, you can also cancel the IAsyncOperation directly like this:

```
var operation = _httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
var response = await operation;

operation.Cancel();
```

This [blog post](http://www.windows8tricks.net/2012/05/diving-deep-with-winrt-and-await/) is a good read on the whole Task vs IAsyncOperation topic.

Comment: Yes this works. Actually today I also looked at sample hosted on MSDN quick uses the same approach. Ref:http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/HttpClient-sample-55700664